# How to extract some missing rows by comparing two different files in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, merge

I have two diferrent files which some rows are missing in one of the files. I want to make a new file including those non-common rows between two files. as and example, I have following files:

file1:

```
id1 
id22 
id3 
id4 
id43 
id100 
id433
```

file2:

```
id1
id2
id22
id3
id4
id8
id43
id100
id433
id21
```

I want to extract those rows which exist in file2 but do not in file1:

new file:

```
 id2
 id8 
 id21
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`comm` utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/comm-invocation.html#comm-invocation) (assumes `bash` as the shell):

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Note how the input must be *sorted* for this to work, so your delta will be sorted, too.

`comm` uses an (interleaved) 3-column layout:

- column 1: lines only in file1
- column 2: lines only in file2
- column 3: lines in both files

`-13` suppresses columns 1 and 2, which prints only the values exclusive to `file2`.

**Caveat**: **For lines to be recognized as common to both files they must match *exactly*** - *seemingly* identical lines that differ in terms of whitespace (as is the case in the sample data in the question as of this writing, where `file1` lines have a *trailing space*) will *not* match.

`cat -et` is a command that visualizes line endings and control characters, which is helpful in diagnosing such problems.

For instance, `cat -et file1` would output lines such as `id1 $`, making it obvious that there's a trailing space at the end of the line (represented as `$`).

---

If instead of cleaning up `file1` you want to compare the files as-is, try:

```
comm -13 <(sed -E 's/ +$//' file1 | sort) <(sort file2)
```

A generalized solution that trims leading and trailing whitespace from the lines of both files:

```
comm -13 <(sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$//g' file1 | sort) \
         <(sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$//g' file2 | sort)
```

<sup>Note: The above `sed` commands require either *GNU* or *BSD* `sed`.</sup>

<sup>Edit: I only wanted to change 1 character but 6 is the minimum... Delete this...</sup>

Comment: no this command does not give the non-common ones as output. did you ever try this  yourself?

Comment: @zara: The updated answer should now provide all guidance that is required to solve your problem. To recap: you were unaware that your `file1` data had a trailing space on each line, which prevented `comm` from recognizing seemingly common lines as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to sort both files then count the duplicate rows and select only those row where the count is 1

`sort file1 file2 | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 1 {print $2}'`